# Piping into `if` returns the pipeline without evaluating it

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I am trying to implement a pipeline that has an optional step **which consists of a pipeline of several functions**. It runs this pipeline based on a condition, and otherwise it just passes through the original value. However I've tried implementing this using `if` and also `purrr::when`, but in both cases the positive case simply returns the pipeline instead of executing it.

Here's a simple contrived example. I've simplified the conditional pipeline to only one function, but being able to use magrittr pipes inside the `TRUE` branch is important here.

```r
library(magrittr)

maybe_round = function(x, round = TRUE){
  x %>%
    `if`(
      round,
      . %>% round(),
      .
    )
}
```

```
> maybe_round(5.3, TRUE)
Functional sequence with the following components:

 1. round(.)

Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

```
> maybe_round(5.3, FALSE)
[1] 5.3
```

This second case is working correctly; it's returning the original value unchanged. But this first case is not, it's returning the magrittr pipeline, but not actually feeding it with `5`. How can I get this to work as I intend? I assume this has something to do with how `magrittr` rewrites the syntax tree, but I can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `. %>% round(.)` means `function(.) round(.)`.  Any time dot starts a pipeline it defines a function rather than being an ordinary pipeline.  Put parentheses around the dot to prevent the dot from starting the inner pipeline.

```
 maybe_round = function(x, round = TRUE){
   x %>%
     `if`(
       round,
       (.) %>% round(),
       .
     )
 }

maybe_round(5.3, TRUE)
## [1] 5
```

Another possibility is to just leave it as a function and then evaluate that function at the outer dot like this:

```
 maybe_round = function(x, round = TRUE){
   x %>%
     `if`(
       round,
       (. %>% round())(.),
       .
     )
 }
```

Comment: I think this is the neatest workaround to this particular quirk of `magrittr`.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to `` `if` `` — the same issue would manifest with any other function. In fact, the issue is the `. %>% …` expression, which is *not a normal pipeline*. Instead, this special syntax creates a lambda (see “Using the dot-place holder as `lhs`” [in the documentation](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html)).

If you insist on using a pipe here, you’ll need to first assign `.` to a different variable name, e.g.:

```
maybe_round = function(x, round = TRUE){
  x %>%
    `if`(
      round,
      {
          x = .
          x %>% round()
      },
      .
    )
}
```

… honestly, I would instead use a regular `if` expression and encapsulate it inside a function that can be piped into, i.e.

```
maybe_round = function (x, round = TRUE) {
    x %>% maybe_round_impl(round)
}

maybe_round_impl = function (x, round = TRUE) {
    if (round) {
        x %>% round()
    } else {
        x
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't pipe again in the  `` `if`() ``.

```
maybe_round = function(x, round = TRUE){
  x %>%
    `if`(
      round,
      round(.),
      .
    )
}

maybe_round(5.3, TRUE)
# [1] 5
maybe_round(5.3, FALSE)
# [1] 5.3
```

Comment: That isn't really solving my problem though, I want to use pipes here because in reality it's a very long pipeline. This is just a simplified example.

Comment: Seems like what you want to do, is to execute everything that is unrelated to the condition inside a pipe, assign to a variable. Then use if statements to complete the rest. 

If this is inside a custom function, have logical arguments which determine whether or not the condition is met.

Or, post the longer code and we can give a solution.

Comment: I have intentionally simplified it because otherwise people will complain. You can trivially make the pipeline longer by just taking `. %>% round() %>% round() %>% round() %>% round()` as the `TRUE` case.

Comment: I have shown a log of running it and you can  see ti works proiperly.